# numpy count occurrences from external set

Tags: python, numpy

I want to count the number each element from a set appears in an ndarray.
Ex:

```
set = {1, 2, 3}
a = np.array([1, 1, 3, 1, 3])
res = {1:3, 2:0, 3:2}
```

Seems like `np.unique` has no option for providing "base" set of elements.
What's the fastest way of doing it?

Comment: Have you tried np.bincount()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your set consists just of small non negative integers then as pointed out by others `bincount` is the way to go.

Here is a method designed for the other case under the assumption that `set` is smaller than `a`:

```
from simple_benchmark import BenchmarkBuilder, MultiArgument
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

B = BenchmarkBuilder()

@B.add_function()
def pp(a,s):
    s = np.array(sorted(s))
    idx = s[:-1].searchsorted(a)
    b = np.bincount(idx,s[idx]==a,s.size)
    if INCLUDE_EMPTY:
        return dict(zip(s.tolist(),b.tolist()))
    else:
        return {k:c for k,c in zip(s.tolist(),b.tolist()) if c}

@B.add_function(alias="Divakar")
def div(a,s):
    u,c = np.unique(a,return_counts=True)
    s = np.array(list(s))
    idx = np.searchsorted(u,s)
    idx[idx==len(u)] = 0 # account for set elements out-of-bounds in a
    mask = u[idx]==s
    cm = c[idx]*mask
    if INCLUDE_EMPTY:
        return dict(zip(s.tolist(),cm.tolist()))
    else:
        return {k:v for k,v in zip(s.tolist(),cm.tolist()) if v}

@B.add_function(alias="use Counter")
def cc(a,s):
    c = Counter(a.tolist())
    if INCLUDE_EMPTY:
        return {k:c[k] for k in s}
    else:
        return {k:c[k] for k in s if c[k]}

@B.add_function(alias="use in set")
def sc(a,s):
    c = Counter(filter(s.__contains__,a.tolist()))
    if INCLUDE_EMPTY:
        return {k:c[k] for k in s}
    else:
        return {k:c[k] for k in s if c[k]}

INCLUDE_EMPTY=True

@B.add_arguments('#a / #set')
def argument_provider():
    short_words = np.array(np.transpose(np.unravel_index(
        np.arange(1024000),6*(26,))),dtype="u4",order="C")
    short_words += ord("a")
    short_words = short_words.view("U6").ravel()
    for exp in range(-10,15):
        ns = int(max(1000,1000*2.**-exp))
        na = int(max(1000,1000*2.**exp))
        s = set(np.random.choice(short_words[:max(exp,2)*ns],ns,replace=False))
        a = np.random.choice(short_words[:max(exp,2)*ns],na)
        yield na/ns, MultiArgument([a,s])

for ratio, args in argument_provider():
    ref = cc(*args)
    for oth in pp,div,sc:
        if oth(*args)!=ref:
            print(ratio,oth.__name__)
            raise(ValueError)
print("all functions appear correct")

r = B.run()
r.plot(relative_to=sc)

import pylab
pylab.savefig('unqsubcnt.png')
```

Produces;

[image: ![enter image description here]

The timings compare my approach ("pp") to @Divakar's, and two non numpy methods based on `collections.Counter`. Please note that this being just an arbitrary  1D sweep may not be representative of the entire parameter space. But assuming it is, we can see that on this occasion non numpy Python "wins".

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way with `np.unique` and `np.searchsorted` -

```
u,c = np.unique(a,return_counts=True)
s = np.array(list(set))
idx = np.searchsorted(u,s)
idx[idx==len(u)] = 0 # account for set elements out-of-bounds in a
mask = u[idx]==s
cm = c[idx]*mask
out = dict(zip(s,cm))
```

Another with `np.bincount` for the specific case of positive numbers in the set and array -

```
c0 = np.bincount(a,minlength=s.max()+1)
out = dict(zip(s,c0[s]))
```